# How do I pass Android App Facebook Review?

Tags: android, facebook, sdk, review

I have had a few round trips with the facebook review team. Some where minor errors, some where crashes. All fixed. When I submit now to the review team, I'm getting the message "Even after logging in, the sharing option gives the error: "Make sure you are signed in." Please look into this, thanks!" Uhhh, Ok?

I know this error is legit because I created it. It's a simple Android Toast message that displays when the logged in facebook user has not "granted" my app the "publish_actions" permission.

This is where things get interesting. So my app fails review because the Facebook tester cannot test the sharing functionality... Uhh duh! I need to pass the review to gain access to that permission (publish_actions)! So now I'm stuck. They will kick it back to me for not being able to test something, that I need to pass their test for! Lol. :)

If anyone has any suggestions for my next submit please feel free? I'm sitting on the fence about programming a Specialized Toast message for the Facebook Review team that quotes directly from the Facebook Review Guidelines about the requirement for the "publish_actions" permission. I'm so close to being done with this app, but I cannot pass the Facebook Submission for the life of me! :) I would just skip this Facebook review stuff, but it's in my project scope so it's required. Thanks in advance for any suggestions / comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how did you implement code for this action. But in my app (always accepted by FB tester), I will ask user for the `publish_actions` when needed:

```
private void askForPublishActionsForScores() {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
        .setPositiveButton(R.string.dialog_yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                // User hit OK. Request Facebook publish permission.
                requestPublishPermissions();                
            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton(R.string.dialog_no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                // User hit cancel.
                // Do somthing!
            }
        })
        .setTitle(R.string.publish_scores_dialog_title)
        .setMessage(R.string.publish_scores_dialog_message)
        .show();        
}

void requestPublishPermissions() {
    Log.d(TAG, "Requesting publish permissions.");
    final Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session != null) {
        Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(this, Arrays.asList("publish_actions"))                    
                .setDefaultAudience(SessionDefaultAudience.FRIENDS)
                .setRequestCode(AUTH_PUBLISH_ACTIONS_SCORES_ACTIVITY_CODE);
        session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
    }
}
```

Then, when you need users must granted the `publish_actions` permission, you have to check:

```
// check to see that the user granted the publish_actions permission. 
if (!permissions.contains("publish_actions")) {
    // the user didn't grant this permission, so we need to prompt them.
    askForPublishActionsForScores();
    return;
} else {
    // the user is granted this permission
    // do something...
}
```

Comment: I implemented this "style" as the solution and re-submitted. :) I'll accept this as my answer if I pass, or if they kick it back to me, and this is "not" the problem anymore. :) Thanks alot. On a side note, does the "publish_actions" permission "expire" after a certain period of time? Is this the reasoning behind facebook mentioning "only request it when you need it?"

Comment: `publish_actions` doesn't expire, it's a `one-time` request, when user accepted this permission, they will not be asked next time. `only request it when you need it` which they meant you shouldn't disturb user when unnecessary :D

Comment: Ahh, perfectly explained. I see. It's more for "user experience" than some framework issue. Thanks. :)

Comment: I have used similar kind of code in my Android native quiz app. Everything works fine with test user. I submitted for review. but it got rejected by mention following reason. "Android
Your app uses a social plugin or share dialog to share content to Facebook. These don't need publish_actions and don't need to be reviewed. Our sharing docs have more information, and you can find the most up-to-date plugin versions here." I am submitting review first time. can you help me? @NhanNguyen

Comment: @MayuriRuparel: just remove `publish_actions` permission as they said due to unnecessary

Comment: @NhanNguyen Then its not allow me to publish score :(

Comment: show you must let they test the function publish score to show them that there are some function in your app need the `publish_action`

Comment: @Nhan Nguyen, simple question, as my app got rejected from fb. Reson was they are not able to login. I will try to explain the case. 1. Created an app, integrated with fb sdk for login and went live. 2. Updating the app to add user_friends permission, cannot test on live app as it already live with only login permission, so created a test app, integrated, all works fine. 3. Sent the test app id build for approval- got rejected. 4. Sent the actual app id build - got rejected. 5. Reson is not able to login. I dont understand the core issue here

Answer (score 0):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8SaFB.png

You should create test users when developing your application.

Then, when you submit your Android app for review, indicate the test user that you used (there's a field for that) so that the Facebook reviewer can replicate the way you use your application.

Comment: I actually do have a test user setup for the review team to use. And I also included the name of the test user in the submission. I hope I pass this time. :)